# Django: How to catch a ValueError from URL?

Tags: python, json, django, uuid

I'm writing a single API function (as I don't need rest in this case).
Basically it's a URL with UUID4 as api-key.

The function goes as follow:

```
def jsonapi(request, apikey):
    try:
        test = get_object_or_404(ProfileDetails, apikey=apikey)
        if ProfileDetails.objects.filter(apikey=apikey).exists():

            details = get_object_or_404(ProfileDetails, apikey=apikey)
            if Posts.objects.filter(published=True, user=details).exists():
                data = Posts.objects.filter(published=True, user=details).order_by('-timestamp')
                postData = []
                for a in data:
                    user = a.user.username
                    title = a.title
                    post = a.post
                    date = a.timestamp
                    slug = a.slug
                    url = "https://app.domain.co/@" + a.user.username + "/" + a.slug
                    # print(date.date)

                    newjson = {
                    "username": user,
                    "title": title,        
                    }

                    postData.append(newjson)
                    jsonStr = json.dumps(postData, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
                    qwe = json.loads(jsonStr)
                    returndata = JsonResponse(qwe, safe=False)
                    returndata['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

                    return returndata

            else:

                newjson = {
                "error": "Please make sure you have at least 1 item live."
                }
                postData.append(newjson)
                jsonStr = json.dumps(postData, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
                qwe = json.loads(jsonStr)
                returndata = JsonResponse(qwe, safe=False)
                returndata['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
                return returndata

        else:
            newjson = {
            "error": "Make sure you have at least one item set as live."
            }
            postData.append(newjson)
            jsonStr = json.dumps(postData, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
            qwe = json.loads(jsonStr)
            returndata = JsonResponse(qwe, safe=False)
            returndata['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            return returndata

    except ValueError:

        return JsonResponse({"Error":"Invalid API Key"})
```

Now basically, what I need it to do is, when I enter something in the URL that's not a UUID, it returns ["'something' is not a valid UUID."]

I would've hoped the ValueError catches the error and let me write a response but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: use regexp at the beginning of your function, raise ValueError in case if it fails

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this in the urls.py, by using a pattern that only matches UUIDs? There's even a [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) for it already.

Comment: try to log line by line in order to find out where exactly the error is coming from. My guess is it's probably from `test = get_object_or_404(ProfileDetails, apikey=apikey)`  in which case you are catching the wrong kind of error. Either way change your exception handler and it might work.  perhaps `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError`  this handler might solve it